# How do we pick the Hex or RGB color code of other colors based on a starting color and mathematics?

Tags: geometry

Ok, so this question may be a little hard to understand, so I will try my best in order to explain what I mean. There are three primary color, namely red, yellow and blue. And if you'd pick the value for red, you can determine what the other color will be by drawing a equilateral triangle.

So let's say I want to pick a whitish, blueish and reddish color. Let's say the value for the reddish color is: #ecaba9, which is pink, how do you determine the two other colors based on that color mathematically (blueish and whitish)?

I think there might be many ways, so I would like one that's based on geometry as much as possible. Or if that's somehow impossible, I don't mind other methods as long as it's explained.

Comment: Your question is indeed hard to understand, but one possibility would be to rotate through the colours, so [#a9ecab](https://www.google.com/search?q=%23a9ecab) (a pale green)and [#aba9ec](https://www.google.com/search?q=%23aba9ec)  (perhaps between a powder blue and lilac)

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to explain what I even mean. What about the color for whitish?

Answer (score 1):

Greenish: $\#a9ecab$, blueish: $\#aba9ec$, whitish: I don't know what you mean, is that some shade of grey?

Those six symbols are three hexadecimal numbers:

$$ab=10\cdot16+11=171, \quad a9=10\cdot16+9=169, \quad ec=14\cdot16+12=236$$

referring to red, green and blue intensity respectively. Notice that $a=10$, $b=11$, ..., $f=15$.

Comment: Yes, gray or white. Isn't the definition of whitish a color between grey and white by default?

Comment: To get that all three numbers should be the same. To have the same brightness set them to $(171+169+236)/3=192=(c0)_{hex}$.

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to apply that formula, what's the hex value for it?

Comment: It is $\#c0c0c0$.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot.